# 16 circuit load center generac to with briggs and stratton

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, transfer-switch

I have a Briggs and Stratton standby generator model 040301 7kw and want to use a Generac automated standby transfer switch with 16 circuit Load center 50amp, part 0j0391. Is this ok?

Comment: Okay, but don't expect to get 50 amps or 16 circuits.  Maybe 2 or 3 circuits at a time, unless they are all bedroom(lights/radio) circuits.

Comment: Can you link the item?  Will it be sufficient for the load to be served? You can [edit] to add details to your question.

Comment: Generic or Generac?

Comment: @crip659  Have to politely disagree with you re capacity.   7KW is a reasonable amount of power and quite a bit can be run on that.  Clearly not an electric range, electric water heater and certainly not much of any electrical resistant heating, but you can run lots of lights (esp if LED), a toaster, coffee maker, TVs, a single element portable burner (about 700- 1,000 watts), fans for a fireplace, etc.   You can get a lot done with 7KW.

Comment: Can you post photos of your existing electrical panel(s) please?

Comment: I agree with George using a larger switch is fine. I tried to look that generator up and it has been discontinued. 
I do not like the 8-10-16 circuit transfer switches . The only advantage is they only only have to transfer the 50 amps so for an automatic model they work, I have wired different brands together  the transfer and start signal were simple circuits but since it’s discontinued you would need to provide the schematic and we can assist.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I need to post this as an answer bc I know I will run out of room as a comment.

Installing an automated stand by generator is not trivial. And why use a "generic" transfer switch?  It really needs to be compatible with the generator. Not only that, in addition to the power cables, there will also likely be a communication cable from the genset to the automatic switch. Who knows if the communication protocol is even compatible. Probably not. But that's just a guess on my part.

You say you have a 16 circuit panel? but mention 50 amps, that sounds odd.  Is this a main panel or sub-panel.

If this is a main panel the transfer switch needs to go between the meter and the main panel.  That means getting the POCO out to pull the meter as well as you having to pull a permit.

If this is a sub-panel, the transfer switch needs be between the main panel feed and the sub-panel.   If so a little easier to install bc you can turn off the breaker supplying the sub.  Still, THIS IS NOT TRIVIAL.   Usually this amount of work requires a qualified electrician and probably also have to pull a permit.

This can't be a hack job (sorry for the terminology).  You'll be fighting an uphill battle trying to connect components from multiple vendors, I doubt it will work.

If I were in your shoes, I'd sell the genset you have and buy one that includes a transfer switch.  Kohler does a good job on these now.  I installed one for my son's new house a couple of years ago and it's great.

Comment: I'm pretty sure *generac* in the title and *generic* in the body are both supposed to be **Genetac** which is a brand of generators and they have automatic transfer switches too. Which may or may not be compatible with other generators,  I have no idea.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  Yes, the OP will have to do quite a bit of research to see if this will work.   Word recognition often screws up and the poster/texter don't catch it.   At least it didn't say "geriatric transfer panel" ...that would be scary!  LOL

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact No. “Genetac” is not a brand. “Generac” is.

Comment: @nobody Arghh! I was typing that on my phone and messed up. **Generac** 100%.

Comment: George these are the most common transfer switches out there most are manual and as such most believe they are a ripoff , compared to a main panel lockout kit at 1/6th the price and no additional wiring. The wiring for the circuits is simple, the gen start and transfer is a bit more complicated but it was not that difficult but definitely a strong intermediate to advanced DIY level electrical background is helpful. As long as the generator has an auto start feature it can be done.

Comment: @EdBeal  Totally agree, once again.   I've installed a couple of MTS with lockouts to comply with code and keep the lineworkers safe.   But the OP wanted, what I think is an fully automatic setup. So placing the auto xfer switch either between the meter and (if so) the main panel is a big deal.  Less so if the OP is trying to feed a sub, but still not at all trivial.    And I TOTALLY AGREE the MTSs sold in the big box stores are a total rip off and require a lot of re-wiring.

Comment: We built our house 2 years ago. I was going to do the same thing you are proposing. Our contract specified a Generac auto transfer switch. I was going to get a Harbor Freight 10Kw generator,  design a sensing circuit, design an auto generator start circuit, an outdoor housing,  etc. When I priced a Generac 22Kw generator it was about 3x what my homebrew system was, but I decided to go with Generac. It is fully integrated and will run the whole house 9 seconds after power loss. I love our Generac system